# problems in server configuration, unable to save images (There was an unexpected error (type=Internal server error, status=500))

Tags: heroku, http-status-code-500

I have implemented my web project selling pizzas to the heroku server. I have also added access to the mysql database ( ClearDB MySQL ), but there is a problem when you enter a pizza in the menu, the registration requires the entry of an image as one of its pizza attributes, and when I press the Save button I get the error: internal server status error: 500. I have searched for documentation on this, but so far I have not found an answer.

`2023-06-28T23: 59: 29.034741 + 00: 00 heroku [ router ]: en = info method = POST path = "/ productos / save" host = nonnasdespliegue.hero.1 conectar = 0ms service = 25ms status = 500 bytes = 704 protocolo = https`

In an attempt to verify if the source code was wrong, I ran the web locally, but with the connection to the database provided by heroku and it worked normally, the images were saved and displayed in the page menu. I would like to know how can I do to solve this problem.